# Unable to reproject geodataframe to EPSG:32634

Tags: geopandas

In order to reproject the geopandas dataframe from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:32634, I wrote the following function:

```
import rasterio
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

def get_field_borders(df_field_polygons):
    df_field_polygons = df_field_polygons.set_crs('epsg:4326')
    print(df_field_polygons.crs)
    data_proj = df_field_polygons.copy()
    data_proj['geometry'] = data_proj['geometry'].to_crs(epsg=32634)
    return data_proj
```

df_field_polygons looks as follows:

```
parent_geom_id                      parent_geom_uuid geometry_name                                           geometry
0           2182452                               2517850      SA-213-1  POLYGON ((20.18828 45.97761, 20.18832 45.97640...
1         861754639  ff8eaa4a-3015-4213-8d5a-6b3fa0d7b53f        SA-104  POLYGON ((20.07577 45.99894, 20.07822 45.99611...
2         863727637  a428db51-1808-441e-9108-2bfd578c11d6        SA-217  POLYGON ((20.17180 45.97331, 20.17184 45.97331...
3         863724345  a5546c5f-9460-49c9-916e-f4b66102e746        SA-137  POLYGON ((20.13306 45.98553, 20.13328 45.98553...
4         863725967  9dbe9bd2-eaa5-41e0-a09c-1aaefdbc1276      SA-147_9  POLYGON ((20.17860 45.98819, 20.17860 45.98819...
..              ...                                   ...           ...                                                ...
```

When I try to run the function above, I get the following output, after which, the execution terminates:

> double free or corruption (out)

Similarly, when I try to read a shape file with EPSG:32634 projection (below example), the execution terminates with the same output message:

```
df_mask = gpd.read_file(mask_path)
with rasterio.open(raster_layer_path, "r") as src:
    print("CRS Raster: {}, CRS Vector {}".format(df_mask.crs, src.crs))
```

Does anyone know what might cause the issue?

## Edit

As in EPSG:4326 projection the points are defined as (lat, lon) tuples, I tried to add the following line before setting the projection:

```
df_field_polygons.geometry = df_field_polygons.geometry.map(lambda polygon: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), polygon))
df_field_polygons = df_field_polygons.set_crs(epsg=4326)
```

After executing the first line, the program terminates and don't know why because there isn't any error message visible upon termination

Comment: is it possible that you have flipped lat and lon ?

Comment: I can see that EPSG:4326 should be (lat, lon). In the dataframe the points are (lon, lat). I shouldn't have set the projection of the source dataframe to 4326. Is there any other way to reproject the coordinates by setting manually the projection to a different format or should I flip lat <-> lon?